# Suitable library to write PDF using Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation

Which library is best to write PDF from HTML using Code Igniter?

Right now I'm using TCPDF, and it's taking much time to load a library.

Comment: It is strange how some people in the CI forum seem to think TCPDF is a solution to this questions like this. I will go ahead with it at least..beside people are expecting PDF generation to be slower than regular html display...otherwise, it is like requesting a printer to print as fast as a screen displays. :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following are some useful PDF libraries & Tutorials for Codeignitor

**[PDF generation using dompdf](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDF_generation_using_dompdf/)**

**[TCPDF-CodeIgniter Integration](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/TCPDF-CodeIgniter_Integration)**

**[Generating PDF files using CodeIgniter](http://www.christophermonnat.com/2008/08/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter/)**

**[mPDF with CodeIgniter](http://tudip.blogspot.com/2012/05/mpdf-with-codeigniter.html)**

**[generating PDF files](http://myphpcodes.blogspot.in/2011/11/creating-pdf-files-with-codeigniter.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this article](http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_community_voice_generating_pdf_files_using_codeigniter). The PDF library used there is quite fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking to convert HTML to a PDF, I highly recommend the wkhtmltopdf.  It uses Qt and WebKit to generate PDF files of rendered markup, and even handles moderately complex JavaScript and AJAX.  This makes it really useful for generating PDFs of pages that you have already created views and templates for, with the added benefit of being able to tweak and debug these pages with your browser.  It works great for generating platform agnostic print views in your web app by normalizing the many nuances of various combinations of operating systems, web browsers, and printer drivers.

It's a stand-alone binary, so you may have trouble implementing it on shared hosting, but I used it recently on a project and could not have been more happy with it.

**wkhtmltopdf:**  http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

**My personal favorite PHP Library and API for it:**
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

Check out **R&OS** library   [R&OS pdf](http://jaison-john.blogspot.fr/2011/02/generating-pdf-using-codeigniter.html)
i find it easy to implement